# show or hide object based on completed field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm pretty new to RoR programming.  I remember reading on some tutorial (forgot which) that it's possible to show or hide a field based on if it is filled out or not.

Something like

```
if @vendor.state.present
  <%= @vendor.state %>
else
  # hide field (don't show to user)
end
```

Is this possible, and do I have the right terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure I understand what you want to do but:

```
<%= "<div>#{@vendor.state}</div>" unless @vendor.state.blank? %>
```

This will output the @vendor.state variable  wrapped in a div tag unless it is nil or an empty string.